# How can I get a column with a filtered result?

Tags: sql

I want to get two columns where I get the numbers of clients that fulfill an specific condition (Product Qty >= 2 or <2)

I have resolved it using two queries by writing the condition as a WHERE statement, however, I want 1 table for all the results. Have a look of what I've tried:

```
select Sucursal, Nombre_Oficial as Oficial, Codigo_Ingreso as Segmento, count(Codigo_Cliente) "Cantidad de Clientes"
from Clientes_MAC
where FechaCarga = (select * from Fecha_Mac)
        and Codigo_Ingreso in ('Preferencial', 'Prestige')
        and Cantidad_Productos >= 2
group by Sucursal, Nombre_Oficial, Codigo_Ingreso
order by Sucursal, Nombre_Oficial
```

AND

```
select Sucursal, Nombre_Oficial as Oficial, Codigo_Ingreso as Segmento, count(Codigo_Cliente) "Cantidad de Clientes"
from Clientes_MAC
where FechaCarga = (select * from Fecha_Mac)
        and Codigo_Ingreso in ('Preferencial', 'Prestige')
        and Cantidad_Productos < 2
group by Sucursal, Nombre_Oficial, Codigo_Ingreso
order by Sucursal, Nombre_Oficial
```

What I want to get is three columns in my query:
- Total client count (easy)
- Clients where Cantidad_Productos < 2
- Clients where Cantidad_Productos >= 2

I know it is not that difficult, probably using OVER and PARTITION BY, but i didnt find the way.

Thanks in advance,

IC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation` for that:

```
select Sucursal, Nombre_Oficial as Oficial, Codigo_Ingreso as Segmento, 
       count(case when Cantidad_Productos < 2 then Codigo_Cliente end) "Less Count",
       count(case when Cantidad_Productos >= 2 then Codigo_Cliente end) "Greater Count",
       count(Codigo_Cliente) "Cantidad de Clientes"
from Clientes_MAC
where FechaCarga = (select * from Fecha_Mac)
        and Codigo_Ingreso in ('Preferencial', 'Prestige')
group by Sucursal, Nombre_Oficial, Codigo_Ingreso
order by Sucursal, Nombre_Oficial
```

BTW -- That `where` clause looks odd `FechaCarga = (select * from Fecha_Mac)`.  Not sure if you meant that or not.  Sample data would help, but you might be better off with a `join`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked. Regarding the where, dont worry, it might look odd by it is quite the same as writing FechaCarga = (select max(fechacarga) from Clientes_MAC) but quicker.